# Deserialising XML To DTOs In Service Reference

Tags: c#, wcf, serialization

I want to use captured SOAP responses as test data. I've successfully got the SOAP XML and now want to use it to populate the DTOs in my project service reference. This is where I'm coming unstuck.

When I use `Message.CreateMessage` in conjunction with either `message.GetBody` or `TypedMessageConverter`, I have a problem where the deserialiser is trying to populate the `PropertyChanged` event handler and throws an exception. Why would it do this and how can I stop it?

**Added From Comments**

Truncated XML:

```
<GetServiceDetailsResponse xmlns="http://thing.com/thing/"> 
  <GetServiceDetailsResult xmlns:lt4="http://thing.com/thing/types"> 
    <lt4:generatedAt>2016-10-14T14:10:39.7718069+01:00</lt4:gene‌​ratedAt> 
  </GetServiceDetailsResult> 
</GetServiceDetailsResponse>
```

Code:

```
string action = null; 
XmlReader bodyReader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(Resources.eg_xml)); 
Message msg = Message.CreateMessage(MessageVersion.Default, action, bodyReader); 
var b = msg.GetBody<GetServiceDetailsResponse>();`
```

Exeption

> SetUp : System.TypeInitializationException : The type initializer for
>   'IntegrationTests.GetServiceDetail.Class1' threw an exception. ---->
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.NetDispatcherFaultException : The
>   formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message:
>   There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter
>   http://thing.com/thing/:GetServiceDetailsResult. The InnerException
>   message was ''EndElement' 'GetServiceDetailsResult' from namespace
>   'http://thing.com/thing/' is not expected. Expecting element
>   'PropertyChanged'.'

Comment: can you elaborate with examples?

Comment: so, i have the (truncated) xml:

Comment: so, i have the (truncated) xml: `<GetServiceDetailsResponse xmlns="http://thing.com/thing/">
  <GetServiceDetailsResult xmlns:lt4="http://thing.com/thing/types">
    <lt4:generatedAt>2016-10-14T14:10:39.7718069+01:00</lt4:generatedAt>
  </GetServiceDetailsResult>
</GetServiceDetailsResponse>`

Comment: the code snippet is: `            string action = null;
            XmlReader bodyReader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(Resources.eg_xml));
            Message msg = Message.CreateMessage(MessageVersion.Default, action, bodyReader);
            var b = msg.GetBody<GetServiceDetailsResponse>();`

Comment: i then get the exception: `SetUp : System.TypeInitializationException : The type initializer for 'IntegrationTests.GetServiceDetail.Class1' threw an exception.
  ----> System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.NetDispatcherFaultException : The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter http://thing.com/thing/:GetServiceDetailsResult. The InnerException message was ''EndElement' 'GetServiceDetailsResult' from namespace 'http://thing.com/thing/' is not expected. Expecting element 'PropertyChanged'.'.`

Comment: @MichaelDickens - In the future, please edit your question to provide examples and code - code does not format well in comments.

Comment: @Tim I realised after posting...

Comment: Can you share the code for the DTO you are trying to deserialize this xml into? From the looks of the error it is expecting a mandatory element '<PropertyChanged>..</PropertyChanged>' in your xml. But since there isn't one its throwing an error.

Comment: @ParagPatil well that's the thing. The propertychanged property has been auto generated as part of the service reference and is obviously being ignored in normal usage as the soap service works. It's only when I try and deserialise